# Django get_query_set ValueError

Tags: python, html, django, url

I'm trying to create a ListView in django for Post categories. So for each post i'm including a link which sends you to a page containing all posts with the same category. I'm using get_queryset on my PostCategoryListView in order to filter them but it shows me the error

```
Field 'id' expected a number but got 'technology'
```

My models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone

class Category(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    image = models.ImageField(default = 'default.jpg', upload_to = 'category_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.type


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete = models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

My views.py :

```
class PostCategoryListView(ListView):
model = Post
template_name = 'blog/category_posts.html'
context_object_name = 'posts'

def get_queryset(self):
    kategoria = get_object_or_404(Post , category = self.kwargs.get('category'))
    return Post.objects.filter(category = kategoria)
```

My anchor tag in htmt:

```
<a href="{% url 'post-category' post.category %}"><h2>{{ post.category }}</h2></a>
```

My urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', PostListView.as_view() , name='blog-home'),
path('post/<str:username>/', UserPostListView.as_view(), name = 'user-posts'),
path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name = 'post-detail'),
path('post/new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name = 'post-new'),
path('post/<int:pk>/delete/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name = 'user-posts'),
path('category/<str:category>/', PostCategoryListView.as_view(), name = 'post-category')
```

]

Can anyone help me understand what is going wrong? So at The last Path I want to use the attribute passed in the url in order to filter my posts by their category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to first look up the Category, and then filter the Posts on that Category. What your code is doing instead is look up a Post using a Category name, and then using that Post as the Category filter... Which doesn't make any sense. :)

What you want to do is:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    kategoria = get_object_or_404(Category, type=self.kwargs.get('category'))
    return Post.objects.filter(category=kategoria)
```